# Show only Followed users post using laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 model `User`, `Follow`, and `Post`

and these relations are like:

`User` model:

```
public function userPosts()
{
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\User\Post');

}
public function follows()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\User\Follow','user_id');

}
public function fans()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\User\Follow','follow_id');

}
```

`Post` Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

`Follow` Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
public function user_follow()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','follow_id');
}
```

Every post belong to some user. and I have a follow list where user have there following user. in follow model there are 2 columns, `user_id` the user whom follow and `follow_id` who follow the user.

now I want to show the post in newsfeed there I want to show the post of user I followed and my post only.

**How can I show them with Laravel eloquent relationship**
I am using Laravel 7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Post::where(function ($query) {
            //generating followers and own user_id array
            $followers = Follow::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
            $followers_and_me = [];
            array_push($followers_and_me, Auth::user()->id);
            foreach ($followers as $item) {
            array_push($followers_and_me, $item->follow_id);
        }

        //query for specific posts
        for ($i =0; $i<count($followers_and_me); $i++) {
            $query->orWhere('user_id', $followers_and_me[$i]);
        }

        })->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
```

Try this one